# Multilingual page association

Tags: i18n-l10n

I would like to know how to switch from one language to another while staying at the same page.
For example if I am at www.mysite.com/en/pageEN then I switch the language and I arrive at the same page but in French:  www.mysite.com/fr/pageFR 
I already use "translate" to translate the content, the path prefix is activated. I do not understand why it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance!